# How to make a script for touchscreen to run after resume?

Tags: scripts, suspend, touchscreen, resume

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on my ASUS TP200SA which is a 2in1 laptop. I have recently noticed a bug about touchscreen, whenever I put the system on sleep and wake it up, touchscreen doesn't work. Since I am quite new to Linux, I only could solve this problem by typing...

```
xinput disable (my touchscreen)
xinput enable (my touchscreen)
```

...these to the terminal. After a while it gets really exhausting and I am looking for a way to automate this process in every resume. I have searched the web and found some tutorial for doing it but I didn't get anything out of it since my experience in Linux is extremely low. I hope someone can explain how to do that in a really simple way.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I have the same laptop , and I have just been able to fix it this way.

First, I created a script

```
sudo nano /usr/local/bin/reload_touchscreen.sh
```

With this code:

```
#!/bin/bash
export DISPLAY=:0.0
export XAUTHORITY=/home/username/.Xauthority
sleep 5s
xinput disable "SIS0457:00 0457:1136"
xinput enable "SIS0457:00 0457:1136"
```

You need to modify "/home/username/.Xauthority" to match your own computer username.
I also found the name of my touchscreen using "xinput list". Update it as well, or use the number id.
I put a 5 second pause so I have time to login back to the desktop, just in case.
Make sure you make this file executable:

```
chmod +x /usr/local/bin/reload_touchscreen.sh
```

Then create a systemd service, with this:

```
sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/reload_touchscreen.service
```

With this content:

```
[Unit]
Description=Reload touchscreen
After=suspend.target
#After=hibernate.target
#After=hybrid-sleep.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/reload_touchscreen.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=suspend.target
#WantedBy=hibernate.target
#WantedBy=hybrid-sleep.target
```

Not sure if it's needed, but I made the service file executable as well.

Then enable the service with this:

```
systemctl enable reload_touchscreen.service
```

I hope it works for you!
PS: I have installed the 4.10 mainline kernel on my laptop, and now the Brightness keys work as well. I think Ubuntu 17.04 will work great on this laptop.